# Breadcrumb for Wpf application

Tags: wpf, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have been working with Breadcrumb for my Wpf application, I achieved it by binding NavigationCommands.NavigationJounal to a datatemplate and overriding the styles of the NavigationWindowUI.
Now my issue is I have two frames in a page, when I navigate the frames individually I get two menu in BreadCrumb(obvious) but I need to have only one menu in BreadCrumb(logically single page).

Below is my implementation in ResourceDictionary

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<client:BreadCrumbPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Button Command="NavigationCommands.NavigateJournal"
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Content="{Binding Name}">
</Button>
</DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: The reason I need to get Single menu is I will be moving the right side frame page to left side frame and populating a new page in right side frame.

Comment: you have to post some miner implementation , show your menu template and style + the code in which the bread crumbs are built .